# Scanned pdf to doc

Tags: pdf

Does anybody know if there is a free online OCR converter that can convert large scanned pdf documents(for instance i want to convert a scanned pdf document of 28MB size)?

I have tried many ocr converters ,but all of them failed.

Comment: @DnrDevil tell me in baby steps how to install it. I dont know anything about ubuntu

Comment: Added an answer for an easy installable program

Comment: Which ones have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can install `ocrfeeder`

[image: OCRFeeder]

You can install it by opening the software center and searching "OCRFeeder" then click install. Or in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ocrfeeder
```

Comment: Shouldn't the update come *before* the install???  **;-)**

Comment: @fabby yea im just use to daily updates so just fetching them is perfectly fine.

Comment: Updated answer for u ;)

Comment: And an upvote for you now!  ;-)